# Higher order differentials – Mistake in textbook?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification, notation, banach-spaces

Let $E=\mathbb{R}^n$, $F$ some Banach space, and let $f\in\mathcal{C}^q(E,F)$. My textbook states that 
$$D^qf(x)(h_1,\dots,h_q)=D(\dots D(Df(x)h_1)h_2\dots)h_q,\quad h_1,\dots,h_q\in\mathbb{R}^n,\quad x\in E,\quad (1)$$

but I think it should rather say 
$$D^qf(x)(h_1,\dots,h_q)=(\dots(D(\dots D(Df)\dots)(x)h_1)h_2\dots)h_q,\quad h_1,\dots,h_q\in\mathbb{R}^n,\quad x\in E.\quad(2)$$

or even

$$D^qf(x)(h_1,\dots,h_q) = D(\dots D(Df(\cdot)h_1)(\cdot)h_2)\dots)(x)h_q,\quad h_1,\dots,h_q\in\mathbb{R}^n,\quad x\in E?\quad(3)$$

Who is right? Is there some identification of spaces that I did miss? Derivatives are continuous linear maps to the book... (Please note that the book is, in general, very precise so the above would be a mistake. This formula is really bothering me, and does so since my very first SE [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851553/using-higher-order-derivatives).)

Comment: I think that you are right. Formula (2) makes more sense when I look at what spaces things belong to.

Comment: @md2perpe yes thank you I think so too, but, now, I think that formula is not what was meant as it just expresses that isomorphism between the multilinear maps and the space of the nested linear maps and seems trivial to me. Could you say something about formula (3)? You could interpret $Df(\cdot)h_1$ as the mapping of directional derivatives $x\mapsto D_{h_1}f(x)$ and so on...